# Will it be a good method to turn on and off GPS when not using, in order to save power?

Tags: android, gps, save, battery

I'm developing an Android application. I needs to read the user's current GPS location periodically (assume in every 1min). In order to save the battery power, I thought of turning off the GPS connection when my app is not reading the GPS values and turn on when it wants to read the location (So in every 1min GPS will be turned on and off).

So my questions are;

1. Is this a good method to save the battery power?
2. Is there any standard method like putting GPS on sleep mode when it is not using?
3. Also will it actually save power by turning on and off the GPS connection?

Answer (score 0):

GPS only needs power when it is actually used, so in theory, turning it off would not save any power.
But, in practice, a lot of apps and services use GPS every now and then, so turning it off would prevent those apps and services to turn GPS on and would therefore save power.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a good method to save the battery power?

No, because one minute is too frequent of a polling period. GPS takes a while to "warm up" (e.g., receive signals from satellites).

> Is there any standard method like putting GPS on sleep mode when it is not using?

Request a less-frequent polling period. Or, if your app will only be distributed via the Play Store, consider using `LocationClient` from the Play Services SDK, as it manages that sort of power tuning yourself.

> Also will it actually save power by turning on and off the GPS connection?

*You* don't turn "on and off" the GPS connection. *You* merely indicate if *your app* needs GPS location data. Whether the GPS radio actually powers down is up to the OS, and that will depend in part on what other applications are running and what they request.

In general, you want to want to unregister from location updates when you no longer need them, and specify a long polling period (e.g., in `requestLocationUpdates()`) to help the OS manage power in between polls.